# Issue with pyspark shell start "cannot import name 'SparkContext'"

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to run pyspark on my local machine `Spark Context` is not being imported somehow this throws an error from one of the spark SQL libraries.

```
(dataplot) name@name:~$ pyspark
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/inkadmin/virtualenvs/dataplot/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkConf
  File "/home/inkadmin/virtualenvs/dataplot/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
  File "/home/inkadmin/virtualenvs/dataplot/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 43, in <module>
    from pyspark.profiler import ProfilerCollector, BasicProfiler
  File "/home/inkadmin/virtualenvs/dataplot/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/profiler.py", line 18, in <module>
    import cProfile
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/cProfile.py", line 10, in <module>
    import profile as _pyprofile
  File "/home/inkadmin/profile.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
  File "/home/inkadmin/virtualenvs/dataplot/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from pyspark.sql.types import Row
  File "/home/inkadmin/virtualenvs/dataplot/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 36, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkContext
ImportError: cannot import name 'SparkContext'
>>>
```